# Assigning an Azure DNS zone to a public VM IP address

Tags: azure, dns

I have a VM with a public IP address which I can access it through internet. I have also a DNS zone in azure with a verified custom DNS name. I have added a recordset in my DNS zone which pointing to my public IP address of VM,

However, when I use the public DNS name on my browser, still I can acesss my CM while when I enter the IP I can access. Can someone point me what are steps to assign a cusmt DNS in azure to a public VM IP in azure?

EDIT:
This is how my DNS looks like, trying to assign my public IP to the custom DNS. I can see the page (running on VM port 80) biy VM public IP (20.185.*.*) but not through custom DNS name(onl*****.com)?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean"still I can acesss my CM while when I enter the IP I can access"? Could you clarify it?

Comment: Why do you use a private DNS zone? The records contained in a private DNS zone are not resolvable from the Internet.  You need a Azure DNS zone for access to your website from the Internet.

Comment: I can visit my webpage (running on port 80) when i use the public ip of VM but not when using the DNS even when I associate the DNS with my public VM IP through azure DNS service

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I am getting you correctly but I have added a picture which elaborate my issue. I am not using a private DNS..

Comment: I have editing my question and added picture for my DNS service which I am trying to associate it with my public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [DNSChecker](http://dnschecker), you could find that domain `onlinexxx.com` has been resolved to another public IP address instead of your Azure VM public IP (20.185..). This is the problem.

To access your websites for external users, you only need to purchase a public domain from a domain provider like [GoDaddy](https://sg.godaddy.com/offers/domains/godaddy-b?isc=gotnbsg01&countryview=1&currencyType=SGD&msclkid=c8dd4383418717e75bd01c27abc2c734&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=en-sg_corp-core_sem_bh_b_exact_new_x_pros_intl_x_001&utm_term=godaddy&utm_content=GD%20Corp%20Core&gclid=CLOJksCi7ewCFQoQjgodAYAAbw&gclsrc=ds) or by an [app service domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#buy-the-domain). then you can add `A` or `CNAME` records to map your VM public IP address or [FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/create-fqdn) in your DNS provider. You even don't need to verify this domain in Azure AD.

In addition, you have the option to [host your domain to the Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns) and delegate your domain in Azure, but this is not very necessary if you want to use your domain provider to host the DNS zones.

Please let me know if you need further help or you can get more DNS troubleshooting steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-troubleshoot).